# How is the law of a stochastic process defined?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(Ω, F, P)$ be a probability space, $T$ some index
set, and $(S, Σ)$ a measurable space. $X : T × Ω → S$ is a
stochastic process. Let $S^T$ be the collection of all functions
from $T$ into $S$.

1. In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_%28stochastic_processes%29):

   > **the law of a stochastic process** is the measure that the process
   >   induces on the collection of functions from the index set into the
   >   state space.   The process $X$ induces a function $Φ_X : Ω → S^T$,
   >   where $$
   >          \left( \Phi_{X} (\omega) \right) (t) := X_{t} (\omega). $$ The law of the process $X$ is then defined to be the pushforward measure
   >   $$
   >          \mathcal{L}_{X} := \left( \Phi_{X} \right)_{*} ( \mathbf{P} ) = \mathbf P \circ \Phi_X^{-1} $$ on $S^T$.

   I was wondering if the $\sigma$-algebra on $S^T$ is defined as $\{ A
       \subseteq S^T: \Phi_X^{-1}(A) \in F\}$?

   Formally, I can understand the meaning of pushforward measure too.
   But I still don't feel it natural, perhaps because I don't actually
   grasp the intuition about the $\sigma$-algebra and  the measure
   $\mathcal{L}_{X}$ defined on $S^T$. So hope to see some insights
   here.
2. When $(S, \Sigma)=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, I heard
   about a different way but cannot remember correctly:

   > $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, t_1, \dots, t_n \in T, B_i \in  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), i=1,\dots,n$, define a subset of
   >   $\mathbb{R}^T$ $$ [B_1, \dots, B_n]:= \{f \in \mathbb{R}^T: f(t_i) \in  B_i, i=1,\dots,n \} $$ and the **$\sigma$-algebra on $S^T$** is the
   >   one
   >   generated from all $[B_1, \dots, B_n]$-like subsets (?).
   >
   > Then define the measure on $[B_1, \dots, B_n]$ to be $$ P(X_{t_1} \in  B_1, \dots, X_{t_n} \in B_n) $$ and extend this in some way to
   >   be a
   >   **measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of $S^T$** (?).

   If the above way (after filling out the question marks) is correct,
   is it equivalent to the Wikipedia way quoted in part 1, for inducing
   $\sigma$-algebra and measure on $S^T$ by the process $X$?

I would also like to know some references that can address my questions. Thanks and regards!

Comment: This is part of my effort to understand [two versions of Ito's isometry](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85962/does-it-isometry-have-different-versions)

Comment: The second construction is called "finite-dimensional distributions". Wikipedia is perhaps not the best place to learn about this.. I would recommend reading the first two chapters of this lecture notes: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/754/